# Trino in Superset SQL Labs shows wrong rows compared to Spark Parquet Tables

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-superset, trino

I have a Parquet file saved as a Table in Spark, which is copied to Trino as a Hive Table (also in parquet format).

My problem is that Superset's SQL Labs, which uses the Trino database is showing misplaced values. I'm querying the Spark Table and it is showing correct values, but SQL Labs is not. Furthermore, I am seeing that the incorrect rows are valid, just misplaced (probably from some other rows).

All this happened when I upgraded my Spark version from 3.1 to 3.2. Our current hunch is that spark has some leftover cache that is being read by Trino, but clearing Sparks's cache using `spark.catalog.clearCache()` did not yield any difference.

Example Spark Table:

```
+----------+----------+----------+
| Column 1 | Column 2 | Correct? |
+----------+----------+----------+
| ABC      | ABC      | Yes      |
| DEF      | DEF      | Yes      |
| GHI      | GHI      | Yes      |
| JKL      | JKL      | Yes      |
+----------+----------+----------+
```

What I see in SQL Labs:

```
+----------+----------+----------+
| Column 1 | Column 2 | Correct? |
+----------+----------+----------+
| ABC      | GHI      | No       |
| DEF      | DEF      | Yes      |
| GHI      | ABC      | No       |
| JKL      | JKL      | Yes      |
+----------+----------+----------+
```

Edit:
Versions:
Spark: 3.2
Trino in Superset: 363
PySpark: 3.2.1
Superset 1.3.1

Comment: What is the SQL generated by superset and have you tried query this directly with trino-cli to see if it fetches correct values? What happens when queried with Hive directly?

Comment: I don't have access to the trino-cli, but I did tried to run a query to trino using the trino-python-client and it returns misplaced values for v0.315 and correct values for v0.306. For direct Hive query, it also return correct values.